# Joining without duplicate records/result sets

Tags: sql, db2

I'm trying to figure out how to join two tables, one of which has essentially duplicate rows, but only return one result set. Basically tableOne has item and category and tableTwo is the only place that has color of the items, but some records in that table have multiple rows for location. There's really no distinction there, it's simply for legacy data purposes.

I just need the color for the item, which will always be the same in tableTwo, but because of the 4 records in table two my below query always returns 4 records where I only want one

tableOne

```
item | category
---------------
 1        A
```

tableTwo

```
item  |  category  |  color  |  location
-----------------------------------------
 1         A           Red        1
 1         A           Red        2
 1         A           Red        3
 1         A           Red        4
```

Query :

```
select t1.item,t2.category,t2.color
from tableOne t1
left join tableTwo t2 
    on t1.item = t2.item 
    and t1.category = t2.category
```

How can I run this to essentially disregard the location and only return one record for the query in DB2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method uses `row_number()`:

```
select t1.item, t1.category, t2.color
from tableOne t1 left join
     (select t2.*,
             row_number() over (partition by item, category order by item) as seqnum
      from tableTwo t2 
     ) t2
     on t2.item = t1.item and
        t2.category = t1.category and
        t2.seqnum = 1;
```

I think you should take `category` from `t1` and not `t2`, unless you explicitly want a `NULL` value when there is no match.

Comment: @TomN. . . . It should.  DB2 has supported `row_number()` for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

Use `SELECT DISTINCT` :

```
select distinct t1.item,t2.category,t2.color 
from tableOne t1
left join tableTwo t2 on t1.item = t2.item and t1.category = t2.category
```